# Tab completion closes SSH connection

Tags: linux, ssh, tab-completion

I am using SSH connection to log into my Raspberry Pi. I used tab completion over SSH before and that worked perfectly. But now I am getting the "connection closed" message whenever I try to use tab completion over SSH.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you log in and check `df -h` to check if space is missing. also a look into logs `less /var/log/syslog` might be helpfull

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume the shell is `bash`.

#### Hypothesis

There is `set -e` in one of your startup scripts. Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> may trigger this: [Enabling `set -e` in the shell causes bash-completion to terminate the shell](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668265).

This is [what `set -e` does](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> Exit immediately if a pipeline […], which may consist of a single simple command […], a list […], or a compound command […] returns a non-zero status. […]

In Bash 4.4.12 in my Debian 9 I can replicate this behavior by invoking `set -e` and then using tab completion like in your screenshot.

#### Testing the hypothesis

Run just `false`. If it exits the shell, it means `set -e` was active. If so, I expect `set +e` to be an ad-hoc fix for your problem. Log in again and check if `set +e` makes the problem disappear. It should.

#### Fixing

You don't want to run `set +e` each time you log in. The real fix is to remove `set -e` from your startup scripts. Files to check:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Some of them may not exist and it's normal. Not every file is used in your particular case, even if they all exist. The list is not exhaustive; these scripts can source other scripts and there is `--rcfile` option of Bash to source any file.

My point is: after confirming that `set -e` is the culprit, you need to track it down in your shell startup sequence and delete it. Investigating why/how it got there may lead to interesting conclusions, but such research is probably not necessary if you just want to fix the issue in question.

Note `bash -e` runs a shell with `set -e` active from the start, so `exec bash -e` in a startup script would give similar symptoms.

Comment: I wish I found this fantastic answer before I spent hours down the wrong rabbit hole. In my `~/.bashrc`, I did `source myscript.sh`, which had `set -e` in it. So when I hit `tab` for completion, it encountered an error code and exited my ssh session. The lesson is don't add `set -e` or `set -u` to scripts that will be sourced, otherwise those options will be set in your main shell!